# Real Time Stream of Data From Databse using PHP

Tags: php, database, stream

I am creating a kind of a social network cum cloud computing script using php. I have successfully completed the news feed part. But now I need to have a real time stream in it. Is it possible with pure php or should we use any other language for it ? I have no idea regarding it. Please suggest me with some good sites regarding it or any idea to complete it. All kinds of helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/load/) over a [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function

That's the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

A "real time stream", in the sense that any new data inserted will be automatically propagated to other clients in (near) real time, is hardly possible with a standard SQL database. Those are based on *queries*, but you need a *push* architecture.

Look into message passing systems, message queues like AMQP or ZeroMQ, PubSub systems, opening and listening to sockets and these kinds of things. You can use them to push data around to subscribers as soon as it happens *in addition to* inserting them into a permanent storage like a database.

If, OTOH, you just mean to automatically update your website every once in a while, use occasional AJAX requests to the server.